# Best way to handle badly written external exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have an external service I'm calling that just returns 500's with the SAME exception each time no matter the issue.

For example(my api to their service):

> **Action:** Fetch image that does not exist
>
> **IMGException:** Status code: 500, ErrMsg: File not found
>
> **Action:** Fetch image that does exist but there are server side issues
>
> **IMGException:** Status code: 500, ErrMsg: Cannot grab img at this time
>
> **Action:** Fetch image that does exist but is expired
>
> **IMGException:** Status code: 500, ErrMsg: Img is expired

What would be the best way to handle this? I was catching them and giving them more descriptive messages to throw to my @ExceptionHandler for logging, etc. Should I just throw them and never catch them since I cannot dependably predict what the exception is caused from and therefore cannot correctly change the status code or message?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `ErrMsg` and throw your own exceptions. But Since the response is from an external service, you can as well include the message from external service in the response to your API in a separate field like `ExternalMessage`.

This will help the users in case the response from external API changes and you end up throwing a different exception.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to simply rethrow these exceptions with the information that the server sends to you and add any information you have. But do not add new information based on what you recieved (with if's, for example), because if they change something your code will just be deprecated.

Of course, never show crypt messages to your final user. In this case add some generic message with instructions about what they can do.